# Show output n numbers of elements as i gives input n numbers of elements?

Tags: java, element

I'm making a simple program in java .. So that as I give input:

> 2 2 4 5

And output will be:

> 2 2 4 5

Whatever I give input it prints the same output.
But before it must ask to input the number of elements first.

**EDITED MY QUESTION**

Okay, so I tried this

```
package com.logical01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] array=new int[100];
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your number elements: ");
        int n_Elements=in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your number now: ");

        for(int i=0; i<=n_Elements; i++){
            array[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

***Output***

```
Enter your number elements: 
5
Enter your number now: 
6
2
1
3
5
6

and it prints..
6
```

Comment: Except for the <= instead of < mistake, I'd use a dynamic array (the ArrayList class in java) for what you do. Try to get rid of numbers within your code, such as your 100. You might have designated this to have no input above 100 elements, but the user might try it anyway. At least try to catch that, like if(n_Elements > 100)... - but again, a dynamic array would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] array=new int[100];
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your number elements: ");
        int n_Elements=in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your number now: ");

        for(int i=0; i<n_Elements; i++){
            array[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<n_Elements; i++){ //you need to loop to get all the values in an array

        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,, .. finally someone answered me with his best.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Move this line:

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

into the for loop just above it.

The reason this program compiles at all is because you have declared `int i;` at the top of the loop.
If instead you moved the declaration *inside* the declaration of the for loop, then it wouldn't compile when you try and do the wrong thing.

```
for(int i=0; i<=n_Elements; i++) {
```

This is an example of *defensive coding*, which protects you against mistakes that might be made elsewhere.

Comment: No bro.. As i put this one `above`. So it'll give an output as i type my input 2 after pressing enter it suddenly prints `2` .. Which i don't want accordingly to `n elements`..

Comment: @rajaetalollo ,So you want to display everything afterwards? If so,create another `for` loop identical to the one you have and use `System.out.print(array[i])` in its body.

Comment: Why does it print 0 though? What is the value of `i` here, which array element is it?

Comment: I want to print my output what i give input ... For instance .. As i give input `0 4 7 8 6 9` it must suppose to give my output as the values what i give input i.e: `0 4 7 8 6 9`.. Now i edited my question .. have a look there please..

Comment: @Deltharis: the reason it printed zero is because zero is the default value of any int that is not initialised, and when you first create an array of ints `int[] array=new int[100];` it is filled with zeroes. After the loop, because i isn't reset, it is equal to the position in the array _after_ the last item entered from System.in, and that value is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

just think about your last line.

What is the value of i?
What is array[0];
What is array[1];
..
What are you printing really - and what do you want to print?

after initializing your array (int[] array = new int[100]), every entry is 0.

try this for debugging and understanding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int[100];

    int i;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your number elements: ");
    int n_Elements = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your number now: ");

    for (i = 0; i < n_Elements; i++) {
        array[i] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("input: array[" + i + "]= " + array[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("printing: i=" + i + "  and array[" + i + "]="
            + array[i]);
}
```